# Terminated due to memory issue when trying to format and upload user contacts in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management

I'm trying to fetch user contacts and upload them to a backend server in a swift iOS app. The backend server takes an array of JSON formatted contacts that should contain some contact info. I'm using [PhoneNumberKit](https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit) for parsing and formatting phone numbers in each contact. I created an array of dictionary ([String: Any]) and loop through the contacts and also loop through the phone numbers of each contact and appending to the array appropriately. 
Here is what the code looks like:

```
func fetchPhoneContacts() {
    let store = CNContactStore()

    store.requestAccess(for: .contacts) { (granted, error) in

        if granted {
            print("granted")

            let keys = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataKey]
            let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys as [CNKeyDescriptor])

            do {

                var contacts = [CNContact]()

                try store.enumerateContacts(with: request, usingBlock: { (contact, stop) in
                    contacts.append(contact)
                })

                self.formatPhoneContacts(contacts)

            } catch let err {
                print("failed to enumerate contacts: ", err)
            }

        } else {
            print("access denied")
        }

    }
}

func formatPhoneContacts(_ phoneContacts: [CNContact]) {

    var payload = [String: Any]()

    var contacts = [[String: Any]]()

    phoneContacts.forEach { (contact) in
        var phoneNumbers = [[String: Any]]()

        if !contact.phoneNumbers.isEmpty {

            for number in contact.phoneNumbers {
                if let formattedPhoneNumber = returnFormattedPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: number.value.stringValue) {
                    let numberDict = ["value": formattedPhoneNumber]
                    phoneNumbers.append(numberDict)
                }
            }

            let contactDict: [String: Any] = [
                "displayName": "\(contact.givenName) \(contact.familyName)",
                "phoneNumbers": phoneNumbers
            ]

            contacts.append(contactDict)
        }
    }

    payload["contacts"] = contacts

    uploadPhoneContacts(payload: payload)
}

func uploadPhoneContacts(payload: [String: Any]) {

    APIService.shared.genericServiceRequest(path: Endpoint.getContacts, requestMethod: .post, queryParameters: nil, bodyParameters: payload) { (response: BasicResponse<GetContactsData>?, error) in

        if let err = error {
            print(err)
            return
        }

        guard let contacts = response?.data?.contact else { return }
        print(contacts.count)
        CoreDataManager.shared.persistJSONContacts(contacts: contacts)

    }

}

func returnFormattedPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: String) -> String? {
    let phoneNumberKit = PhoneNumberKit()

    do {
        let phoneNumber = try phoneNumberKit.parse(phoneNumber)

        return(phoneNumberKit.format(phoneNumber, toType: .e164))
    } catch {
        print("Generic parse error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    return nil
}
```

when i run the app in simulator, everything works fine and even on a real device with higher memory. but when i run it on older devices (e.g. iPhone 5s) I get a crash `Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue`.
Could the creation of dictionaries and array of dictionaries inside a loop cause the issue? How can i improve the code to avoid this crash, especially when trying to upload a lot of contacts?

Comment: keep all the inside loop local variables allocations with @autorelease pool

Comment: this solved it, cut the memory usage to about 10%. thanks